# Kron for Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to find Kronecker product for 2 sparse matrices. My code is the following.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix, kron
dx = np.linspace(0,1,5)
x = populatematrix1(len(dx))
print x.shape, type(x)
y = populatematrix2(len(dx))
print y.shape, type(y)
z = kron(x,y)
print z.shape
```

I checked the two functions used to populate sparse matrix. They work very well. The problem comes up when I take the Kronecker production between 2 sparse matrices.
The result I got is the following:

```
(3,3) <class 'scipy.sparse.dia.dia_matrix'>
(3,3) <class 'scipy.sparse.dia.dia_matrix'>
(3,3)
```

The first two lines are the shape and type of x and y. The last line is the shape of z.
If z is the Kronecker product, the shape should be (9,9).
Why do I get (3,3)? Thank you very much.
Here is the simplest definition for `populatematrix1` and `populatematrix2` and `populatematrix2` is the same with `populatematrix1`

```
def populatematrix1(dim):
    return dia_matrix( (np.array( [np.array([2]*5),np.array([1]*5), np.array([1]*5)] ),np.array([0,1,-1]) ),shape=(5,5))
```

Comment: I've tried `kron` with a bunch of different `dia_matrix` matrices, and I can't reproduce this.  Could you add enough code so that we can run the exact same code that you are running and see if we get the same result?  If you can, simplify the code to the minimum that produces the unexpected result.

Comment: I tried this with some diagonal and some 'highly non diagonal' `dia_matrix` matrices, produced using different initialisations, and also cannot reproduce this. As @WarrenWeckesser says, it would be necessary to know what `populatematrix1` and ~2 do in essence such that the bug appears. Is the type of your `z` matrix "Block Sparse Row"?

Comment: @Warren Weckesser, I add the definition of populatematrix1 and populatematrix2 in the question.

Comment: Setting `populatematrix2 = populatematrix1` and running exactly the code you put up, I get 

```(5, 5) <class 'scipy.sparse.dia.dia_matrix'>
(5, 5) <class 'scipy.sparse.dia.dia_matrix'>
(25, 25)

In [7]: type(z)
Out[7]: scipy.sparse.bsr.bsr_matrix
```

Sorry for the lost formatting, the bottom line is that it seems to work on my computer

Comment: @eickenber, the code works now. I don't know how is going on. Thanks for your help.